# VS2010 WPF, different applicationicon and splash for separate configurations

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am attempting to have multiple configurations in my WPF project where each is different branding. I have created a configuration for each brand based on the release configuration of the generic build. I have a custom #define in each configuration for #if'ing my c# code and seem to be successfully generating a separate build in a folder for each configuration.

How can I change the applicationicon and splash to be different for each configuration?

Here is what is in my csproj file:

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <SplashScreen Include="mysplash.png" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationIcon>MyIcon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm trying to do the same for ApplicationIcon.

Comment: My similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759273/set-a-different-applicationicon-for-each-build-configuration

Comment: @Grant - The answer to your posted question is how I did it. Works for splash the also.

Comment: Yep, that guy nailed it.  Stupid windows.