# What is the best way to duplicate a .csproj (for creating the same app with different named exes)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, configuration

I have a solution in visual studio where one project (.csproj) is set to create an exe.
I would need to create a duplicate copy of this project so that I can name it something different and change the icon for it. (All of the rest of the projects can stay the same)

I am using conditional compilation symbols for that project, but I don't want to create a whole separate solution configuration because that requires expensive rebuilding of the entire solution.

Comment: can't you just use different build targets?

Comment: I don't think you realise how expensive the maintenance will become

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a copy of the project on disk (outside Visual Studio) and add the copied project to the solution. Then you can modify output assembly name, icon. etc..

However better practice would be to perform the necessary operations as postbuild step (e.g. batch/powershell script) as you will have to keep the projects synchronized (added/renamed/removed files, references...)

Comment: I ended up doing this option. My philosophy was "build everything first, then copy the correct exe names into their respective installer projects (these are for oem agreements where the companies need differently named exes)

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio under Build -> Configuration Manager,   you can create a new configuration for your project and clone it from your release build,  then in your project properties you can customize it.

For the icon, you'll want to refer to [Set a different ApplicationIcon for each build configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10759273/set-a-different-applicationicon-for-each-build-configuration)

Comment: When you use two configurations, you have to execute build twice, I think, compared to post build step/script.

Comment: under visual studio 2012, under Build it has "Batch Build" and you can build them all at once.  Not sure if its 2010 or not

Comment: In my version of 2010, I see no batch build option.  Edit:On closer inspection, there is.

Comment: @KeithNicholas That's insightful. I'll have to check out batch build.

Answer (score 0):

Copy it somewhere else and change the assembly name and namespace may be on the project property window( right click and property)

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what your trying to accompish but possible solutions:

1. add post build event that will copy exe / (exe ad dll-s) to another directory
2. if you use TFS, edit your Build so it will create copys

Cheerz,